# How to model in UML Use Case Diagram a different external system based on the role of the primary actor?

Tags: dependencies, uml, use-case-diagram

I am modeling a software that requires to be interfaced with an optical tracking sensor, to measure the pose of some objects through optical markers.
A general user interacts with this sensor (say External System 1) in two different use cases (say UC1 and UC2). 
I would like to model also the possibility that an admin user interacts with the software through the same use cases UC1 and UC2, but he can be interfaced with a software simulator (say External System 2) that simulates the real optical sensor.

I'm trying to model this scenario in a Use-Case diagram, but I am uncertain about the proper modeling of the presence of the simulator and the admin role.
I wouldn't create a second pair of Use Case, because they are supposed to be exactly the same adopted by the general user. 
With reference to the Figure, I thought to add some dependency arrows (dashed) from the UCs to the External System 2 also, but this way would sound as also the general user could interact with the simulator, while this should not be allowed.

[image: Use-Case diagram draft]
I apologize if this question could appear to be quite trivial, but these are my first experiences with software UML modeling.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Do you mean you want to either have a real physical sensor or a simulator and don't know how to model that? Is the simulator used for specific reason (e.g. for calibration)? Note that the actor is a role so if you can have either an actual equipment (a real optical sensor) or a dummy (a software pretending to be one) stepping into the role it doesn't matter and you just model it once.

Comment: The simulator is basically thought for training or testing purposes, when the real optical sensor is not available. I could think to model additional functionalities that are specific of the simulator, but I'm not taking them into account now. My doubt is more evident when going down in the particularization of the design. For instance, sketching a contest diagram, I thought I would need one Proxy service for the real sensor (that uses the APIs of the device) and one Proxy service for the simulator (that uses the APIs of the simulator). Is there any conceptual mistake in my reasoning?

Comment: It would certainly help to name the UC correctly. UCs are about real world things and lifting them on numbered items will disable meaningful discussions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with looking at your basic system like this

[image]

So basically your system is measuring something using a sensor. This `Sensor` can be either a real sensor or a simulator. `User` must not really care (though he knows what is attached). But the *Measuring System* will really not (!) care. So the simulator must simulate whatever is needed so the system will think it's a normal sensor.

Now that simulator is another system:

[image]

From the perspective of that system you look at *Measuring System* as external actor. Plus it offers an admin the possibility to set parameters for the test cycle.

Comment: Maybe I couldn't clarify one of my requirements: I would like the access to the simulator to be granted only to an admin user, while a general user should not.
In addition, this solution would assume that the Measuring system will contain independent code from the type of sensor (real or simulated), while in my idea it should contain the corresponding APIs. Is it a wrong perspective for the design?

Comment: You're probably not clear about your system design. That's why I suggested to start from a clear and simple point. You could simply apply a constraint to the `User` actor that tells `{ if the simulator is used only an admin can run the measurement}` or something along those lines.